# What are the available metrics and dimensions for the AWS/ECS/ManagedScaling namespace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

Currently looking at monitoring AWS/ECS/ManagedScaling metrics - but there seems to be no documentation available in the AWS documentation related to these.

I can only find https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html#available_cloudwatch_metrics - but this is only for AWS/ECS.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you know `AWS/ECS/ManagedScaling` namespace exist? Can you see it in your CloudWatch Metrics?

Comment: Yes - but I can only see 1 metric (CapacityProviderReservation). And the namespace is documented here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aws-services-cloudwatch-metrics.html but the linked document there does not contain any information on the metrics (only AWS/ECS ones)

Comment: So maybe that's the only metric available.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that simple - some metrics in other service namespaces do not show up if they have no value. Additionally, the dimensions are not documented as well.